# How to parse XML file with BeautifulSoup and regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a XML file such as the following. And I would like to parse through it and replace every single instance of `\/u\/corpora` to `/my/datafiles`.
Below is my file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<corpus name="data_name">
        <speaker-description name="M05">
                <gender>male</gender>
        </speaker-description>
        <recording audio="/u/corpora/BUS.wav" name="BUS">
                <speaker name="M05"/>
                <segment end="inf" name="1" start="0">
                        <orth> WORDS </orth>
                </segment>
        </recording>
        <recording audio="/u/corpora/BUS1.wav" name="BUS1">
                <speaker name="F05"/>
                <segment end="inf" name="1" start="0">
                        <orth> WORDS </orth>
                </segment>
        </recording>
```

However, below code gives me a TypeError.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

_file = BeautifulSoup("/Users/Desktop/my_file.xml")

while re.search(r'\/u\/corpora', _file):
    _file = re.sub(r'\/u\/corpora', r'/my/datafiles', _file)
```

How can I replace these patterns?

Comment: This is one of the only cases I wouldn't bother with using an xml parser. Your search and replace is simple to the point where you don't even need regex. You can do a simple str.replace()

Comment: Also, `/` is not special and doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: how do I use str.replace()? because it's part of the string and I think I would need to use regex?

Comment: "a TypeError": post the full traceback. It contains more useful information beyond just "a TypeError".

Comment: `with open("/Users/Desktop/my_file.xml", "r") as f: print(f.read().replace("/u/corpora", "/my/datafiles"))`